# How to start a service before application on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

so I have this wpf application that consume a service on the same solution.
I would like to when I start the aplication it automatically run the service first, how can I do that?
Currently, i have to manually start a new instance of the service and only after I can run the application, otherwise it give me an error saying that the connection to the service timed out.

EDIT: WCF Service btw

Comment: How you do this depends on the type of service you are talking about. Are you talking about a "Windows Service" or a "WCF Service"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio lets you [start up multiple projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx) from the same solution at once when you debug. Just go in to your solution properties and set the "Startup Project" to `Multiple startup projects` then select both your WPF App and your WCF Service.

[image]